# Laplace Transform in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, transform, transfer-function

I have some input data, and output data and i want to evaluate the Transfer Function, and "Impulse Response".

I want the Transfer Function for a Sine Wave, and the Impulse Response for a Dirac Delta impulse, both have their input,and output data.

I know that i should take the Laplace Transform of the output data, and divide it with the Laplace Transform of the input data and that will give me the Transfer function. And i can also get the Impulse Response as the Inverse Laplace Transform of the Transfer Function.

Is there a pre programmed package in python for Laplace Transforms? I found an inverse Laplace mpmath.invertlaplace, but i didnt found any for Laplace.